# HTML5 date picker with small width doesn't show full date in Chrome

Tags: html, css, forms, date, google-chrome

When I have a standard Html5 date picker with a small width, I don't see the full date on Chrome even there is theoretically enough space to display it.

[image: white space overlaying input]

Is there any way on how to fix this behaviour of the HTML5 Datepicker?

```css
#myDate {
  width: 110px;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="myDate">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/weseba/ghp764n0/7/

Comment: Don't set the width so narrow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yeah, you can set `margin: 0` for calendar-picker:

```css
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="myDate" name="trip-start"
       min="2014-01-01" max="2021-12-31">
```

Comment: Note: You can see these elements in Chrome's dev tools with a [settings change](https://iamnickdavis.com/inspect-placeholder-styles-developer-tools/).